# Proof: $Ax=x$ for all $x$ implies $A=I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square matrix of order $n$ and let $x$ be an $n$-vector.

Prove that if $Ax=x$ for all $x$, then $A=I$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try setting x to the vectors in the basis:
x = (1, 0, 0, ...), (0, 1, 0, 0, ...), ...
What does Ax = x for these vectors say about the coefficients in A?

Comment: Can you show that if $Bx = 0$ for all $x$, then $B = 0$?

Comment: No effort? Just want us to do your homework for you?

Comment: @TedShifrin It is not a homework. Only case I can prove is when $n=1$.

Comment: Then you haven't tried very hard. See @T.Bongers's suggestion. It's not homework? Then where does this come from magically?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am currently trying that.

Comment: Consider [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/587436) answer together with T's comment.

Comment: @GitGud This was quite useful thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be kind of difficult to get started with a proof for "for all..."- or "there exists..."-type statements, as straightforward algebraic manipulation usually won't lead to the answer directly. Instead, some kind of insight or theorem usually has to be used.

When we want to prove that A = B, it's sometimes wise to prove A - B = 0 (where 0 can mean the number 0, or an element from a field that has 'the same role'). For matrices, we indeed have such an element: the null matrix, with all it's coefficients equal to zero.

(I have to admit, this wasn't in the direction I was thinking, but it is probably the easiest way)

Now we have $(A - I)x = Ax - Ix = x - x = 0$. So the proof comes down to proving that $B = 0$ from $Bx = 0$ with $B = I - A$. You can do this in some different ways.

A high-level way would be to use the matrix norm. We have
$|Bx| = |B||x| = 0$ even if $|x| > 0$, so we have to conclude $|B| = 0$ so $|B = 0|$.

Probably better suited is to look at the products of $e_1 = (1, 0, 0, ...)$, $e_2 = (0, 1, 0, ...)$, ... with the matrix $B$. They are all zero. But the product of $e_i$ is exactly the $i$th column vector from $B$. Because this is zero, all the coefficients in the $i$th column from $B$ must be zero, for each column. Zo $B$ has all coefficients equal to 0.

---

EDIT:

### Probably a better way

Using again that $Ae_i$ equals the $i$th column vector from $A$, we can easily see that $A$ is the matrix created by lining up $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_n$: the identity matrix of size nxn.

Comment: Many thanks, probably would have never thought of that. This is my first proof intensive course. We didn't even study standard vectors (although I know about them) but I can probably define them and use them. Again, this proof is not to be graded by my instructor. I don't get any credit for this (except if it comes up on my finals :D).

Comment: +1. The "Probably a better way" is, in my view, probably the *best* way. When I'm constructing matrices for linear transformations "in my head", I use the fact that the $i$th column is where the transformation takes the $i$th standard basis vector. It's a very handy way of thinking about these things.

Comment: I agree, this way provides more insight and it is a good property to know. One could argue that trying to prove it the first way makes for a better exercise (as often, there is not such a simple solution to be found).

Answer (score 3):

Suppose a matrix $A$ is *not* zero. Without loss of generality, it's first column $C_1$ is nonzero. Then $Ae_1=C_1\neq 0$.